# Can't get stylesheet to work with ejs for node.js

Tags: node.js, express, stylesheet, ejs

I'm trying to make a simple server with node, express and ejs for the template. I've gotten the server to point to the page, load it, and am even able to generate other bits of code with the include statement. However for some reason the style sheet will not load.

app.js

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
http = require('http'),
server = http.createServer(app),
fs = require('fs');

var PORT = 8080; 

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.render('board.ejs', {
    title: "anything I want",
    taco: "hello world",
    something: "foo bar",
    layout: false
  });
});


app.listen(PORT);
console.log("Server working");
```

The ejs file is in a directory views/board.ejs

```
<html>
 <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='../styles/style.css' />
 </head>
 <body >
    <h1> <%= taco %> </h1>
    <p> <%=  something %> </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

and style.css is in a styles/style.css directory relative to app.js

```
p {
  color:red;
}
```

I've tried every path that I can conceive of for the href of the link including relative to where my localhost points relative to app.js relative to board.ejs and even just style.css but none seem to work. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Declare a static directory:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

<link rel='stylesheet' href='/style.css' />
```

Comment: that didn't seem to work. Why `'/public'?` and how would setting the app.use change how the stylesheet is evaluated? I also tried setting to `href='/styles/style.css'` with the change and without any luck

Comment: put it above your app.router() line.

Comment: You're basically talking to your .ejs file and saying that when you reference a static file, like in the `link` tag above, the root directory is the `public` folder you defined in app.use, rather than the root directory of your entire app.  In this case, the "/" in the href of the link tag references the `public` directory, not the root of your app.

Answer (score 12):

in app.js:

```
 you must first declare static directory 

app.use("/styles",express.static(__dirname + "/styles"));
```

in ejs file :

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/styles/style.css' />
```

Comment: That is very good answer! If you are trying to use like me some relative path based on the file location e.g. href='../../styles/style.css' you are going to have problems if you have some templates (e.g. css/js resources that are included in every file). In short - when you user "/bla/bla" (slash/bla/bla) you are working with the statics directory. Good.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I was working with this same thing and my CSS was not working. Finally, I get the trick. My static path was like below,

```
const app = express();
const publicDirectoryPath = path.join(__dirname, '../src/public');
const staticDirectory =  express.static(publicDirectoryPath);
app.use(staticDirectory);
```

and my folder structure was like

[image]

The trick is that express access only defined static path, in my case CSS was outside of public so it was not working and suddenly I move CSS folder inside my public folder and that's it. Works beautifully.

Above example was for only one static path. For multiple static path you can use the code in the below

```
const app = express();
const publicDirectoryPath = path.join(__dirname, '../src/public');
const cssDirectoryPath = path.join(__dirname, '../src/css');
const staticDirectory =  express.static(publicDirectoryPath);
const cssDirectory =  express.static(cssDirectoryPath);


app.use(staticDirectory);
app.use('/css/',cssDirectory);
```

And my generic HTML file is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Index</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="../css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>this is index page</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, is it possible that `const publicDirectoryPath = path.join(__dirname, '../src/public');`  could be shortened to  `const publicDirectoryPath = path.join(__dirname, '/public');`? It looks like this path is relative to the app.js file, so `../src/` would be going from `src`, up a level to the root directory, then back to `src`?

Comment: No I don't think so

Answer (score 0):

To set the entry point for your application dependancies like css, img etc add below line into your server.js (or which ever being used).

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'))
```

This tells to get css files from current directory where server.js is present. Accordingly you can define relative path of css in html file.

Answer (score 0):

With Express 4, you can easily set this up by using the following within your app.js file.

```js
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname,'pub')));
```

Place this early in your file, after you created your require constants, and declared your express app.

Its declaring a static directory, with the help of the path object, allowing you to have a place where all of your front-end resources are available. It's also giving it a virtual directory name (/static) that can be used on the front of the site, instead of the physical name you see within your project (/pub).

In your template  you can do something like this in your head

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css_bundle.css"/>
```