# Docker or nodemon: reloading issue

Tags: node.js, docker, nodemon

Is there any reason why nodemon in a Docker container stop reloading?
I have not had any problems with reloading till half way through the project. Now I have to `docker-compose down` and `docker-compose up` to see any changes (plain text, js or styles). I am not getting any errors. I have tried changing the package.json file to `"start": "nodemon --legacy-watch"` and I am still having the issue.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "mongoose-express-docker",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Simple learning environment.",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start:express": "node ./app.js",
    "start": "nodemon --legacy-watch",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "method-override": "^3.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.7",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.6",
    "ejs-mate": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  nodejs:
    image: nodejs_mongo_docker
    build: .
    user: node
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    links:
      - mongodb

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:4.0.24
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - data:/data/db
    command: mongod --port 27017 --bind_ip_all

volumes:
  data:
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.16.1-alpine3.10
ENV NODE_ENV production
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN npm install nodemon -g
COPY ["package*.json", "./"]
RUN npm install --production --silent && mv node_modules ../
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD npm start
```

Full Code: https://github.com/melissakipp/yelp-camp

Comment: I'm not sure if I need to delete the question... I am still having issues with nodemon not reloading without bring the containers down and back up again, but I found out why my styles where not be applied. I found the solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13486838/cant-get-stylesheet-to-work-with-ejs-for-node-js

Answer (score 0):

Resource: https://github.com/remy/nodemon#application-isnt-restarting

**Application isn't reloading** 
"..networked environments (such as a container running nodemon reading across a mounted drive)..."

I needed to add a nodemon configuration to my progject. There are two ways to add, one is making a separate file called nodemonConfig.json and the second option is to add `"nodemonConfig": {}` to my `package.json` file.

After a few trials and errors, I found that this combination worked.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "mongoose-express-docker",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Simple learning environment.",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start:express": "node ./app.js",
    "start": "nodemon -L ./app.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "nodemonConfig": {
    "restartable": "rs",
    "ignore": [
      ".git",
      "node_modules/**/node_modules"
    ],
    "verbose": true,
    "execMap": {
      "js": "node --harmony"
    },
    "legacyWatch": true,
    "ext": "ejs, js, css"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "docker",
    "ejs",
    "express",
    "mongoose",
    "nodemon"
  ],
  "author": "Melissa Kipp",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.1",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.5.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.6",
    "ejs-mate": "^3.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "joi": "^17.4.0",
    "method-override": "^3.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.7",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```